# Where is the Gorhart Special Delivery Chest?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Several of the unlockable items for KoA from the Demo mention that they show up in the Gorhart Special Delivery Chest, but for the life of me, I can't seem to find it.

Where is this chest? Does it exist in the demo, or just in the main game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never looked for it in the demo ([though Paul Z says its there](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49959/3062)), but it is definitely in the main game, outside the building just beyond the well in the center of town, where a group of people are gathered around the wounded Fae when you first arrive.

[image]
[image]

I had the following items inside:

- Twinned Souls
- Shepard's Cuirass
- Shepard's Chausses
- Shepard's Helm
- Shepard's Gauntlets
- Shepard's Greaves

All of the "Shepard's" gear requires Might 3 to wear. Looting it all from the chest unlocked a new destiny for me. I don't know if it would be in there for everyone, or just for those who pre-ordered Mass Effect 3 like I did.

Comment: Yep, it's in the same place in the demo. Nice pics!

Answer (score 0):

It's in the demo, just outside the inn in Gorhart (to the left of the door). However, the stuff doesn't show up there in the demo, so you can look inside but it's always empty. Presumably it does work in the main game; I don't have early access so I don't know yet!